# Feed Dict Error in Tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am attempting to build a Multi Layer Perceptron (MLP) in Tensorflow. I am using a dataset generated using numpy. The dataset has just two variables, one of which is the label. The dataset contains `100` points normalised in the range `[0-1]`.

```
print(trainX[0:3])

[ 0.2853112   0.2433195   0.56746888]
```

All values above `0.5`, have the label `1`, otherwise they have a label `2`.

```
print(trainY[0:3])

  [2 2 1]
```

The problem occurs in the `tf.Session()` loop.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(init)

    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        #avg_cost = 0.

        for (xs, ys) in zip(trainX, trainY):
            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X:xs, Y:ys})
```

**The script terminates at that last line**, with the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Expected begin[0] == 0 (got -1) and size[0] == 0 (got 1)     when input.dim_size(0) == 0
 [[Node: Slice_132 = Slice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Shape_134, Slice_132/begin, Slice_132/size)]]
```

Further up in the script, I declare the placeholders as follows:

```
X = tf.placeholder("float")
Y = tf.placeholder("float")
```

I am happy to post more code; in the interests of being succinct, I have not (so far) posted everything.

Comment: Can you provide more code? It looks like you have an invalid slice operation somewhere in your code.

Comment: Hi Neal, I wrote out the full script. I can post back to so the code causing the problem. https://github.com/miramolin/TensorFlowTutorials/blob/master/TFRoughlings.ipynb

Answer (score 1):

Try to modify your label index which should be start from 0. In your case,      `trainY = np.array([1, 1, 0])`. I think it would solve your problem.

Comment: Maybe you have some error in your trainX, not trainY, according to the error traceback